# Hadoop standalone installation - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused error while running jar

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop and I was trying to install Single node standalone Hadoop in Ubuntu 14.04. I was following the Apache Hadoop [Document](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html) and as it is given there, when I tried to run

```
$ bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.5.0.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

I got the `java.net.ConnectException` message:

> Call From a1409User/127.0.0.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection
>   exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more
>   details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

I checked in http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused where it has been asked to verify that there isn't an entry for hostname mapped to 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1 in /etc/hosts. Though this point is not so clear to me, I tried by changing the given IP and mentioning the port number but no luck. I also checked with telnet:

```
$ telnet localhost 9000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Did you start the cluster with start-all.sh?

Comment: Yes I did. Also I checked the services by `jps` command

Comment: which hadoop version are you trying to install? please use the document of the same version

Comment: Hadoop version 2.5.0. I am using the doc of the same version (link given in question)

Comment: what is the output of jps? try using netstat to see if it is listening at 9000. also try setting up pseudo distributed as i did

Comment: @ Antariksha Yelkawar Here is the output:

`5949 NameNode
6244 SecondaryNameNode
6076 DataNode
6458 ResourceManager
7266 Jps
6593 NodeManager`

Comment: did you set the properties in core-site.xml? also try this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-on-ubuntu-13-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to format namenode. Also in your script `input` and `output` directories must be given. For example:

```
hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.5.0.jar grep /user/hadoop/hadoop-config /user/hadoop/output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

After that you can check the content in the output directory by:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/hadoop/output/
```

It should print output as follows:

> Found 2 items
>   -rw-r--r--   3 hadoop supergroup          0 2014-09-05 07:55 /user/hadoop/output/_SUCCESS
>   -rw-r--r--   3 hadoop supergroup        179 2014-09-05 07:55 /user/hadoop/output/part-r-00000

Answer (score 0):

1. Confirm you are in Local (Standalone) Mode. I think you are not in the Standalone mode.

> May be you have tried the another step. Make sure you are not config the **etc/hadoop/core-site.xml**  and **etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml**.

2. If you are want to try Pseudo-Distributed Mode .

> Try config the **etc/hadoop/core-site.xml**  and **etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml** again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure HDFS is online. Start it by `$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh`